# public database available for testing email security proposal?

Tags: databases, data-leakage

I would like to test a model for preventing information leakage in an environment that consist of the following:

- a group of senders of emails or messages
- a group of receivers of the emails of messages
- a set of connections established between the users of the two groups aforementioned

I found that the Enron database has a figure like the one that I am looking for, but the problem is that it did not have cases of information leakage as far as I know. For that reason, I would like to know if there are some public datasets available that could help me to test my model. The datasets that I am looking for are those that describe cases of leakage caused by email messages.

Comment: I honestly can't really tell what you are trying to accomplish, but questions seeking product recommendations (which I feel that this is) are off topic on [security.se]. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help].

Comment: You want a complete set of emails from an organization that includes a case of data leakage to test a model on? You can see the conflict here, right? If there was data leakage, why would that set of emails be *deliberately* released to the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The datasets that I am looking for are those that describe cases of leakage caused by email messages

That's a concrete question, but asking for a database to do this is only relevant if you know more about how.

You ask about *prevention*; the only way to prevent accidental leaks is to have a clear user interface, that requires you to manually add recipients, and maybe alerts you when you supply lists of people as recipients. Data analysis doesn't really have a place there.

But intentional leaking could happen by downloading it to a memory stick and walking out. [It's really hard to stop that.](https://youtu.be/TF4bD0fb_Vw?t=1m18s)

Now if you're talking about *detecting* cases of information leakage after the fact, that's another story.

Luckily, [most](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c) email [providers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) have [an](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/what-privacy-yahoo-still-retains-copy-your-emails-after-they-are-deleted-your-inbox-1572381) audit log, because of strict [rention policies](http://www.debrauw.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/EU-Retention-Guide-2014.pdf). Any suspected leaks can be investigated there.

If you're talking about actually detecting information leaks as they happen, you either need to specify who can talk to who, or detect anomalous behaviour by training data analysis models. Facinating stuff, but [better suited for Statistics SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/how-to-get-started-with-neural-networks)

Comment: thank you for your answer, one more question; how can I detect anomalous behaviour on a data leakage scenario? I mean is there any information on the current literature about those cases? I have searched, but apart of a couple of papers I was not able to find anything else.

Comment: Yes, the papers you found should be more than enough to figure out how it works.Detecting Privacy Leaks
Using Corpus-based Association Rules by Chow et al.  Has some great techniques.  I'm afraid there aren'the many commercial sources for what you want because it is so advanced.

Comment: To add to this, there are some commercial solutions in DLP you can check out. Symantec, Forcepoint and Microsoft Azure have started incorporating machine learning and anomaly detection into their products over the last few years. I haven't been able to find a dataset that might fit your needs.